# sound to light circuit sensitivity and doubts

Tags: circuit-analysis

Are there problems with this sound to light circuit? first diagram is the original circuit designed by a famous person, second one is my similar copy, and last photo is the prototype board that I have been testing for hours with different values.

When the values of the original were used, I found it very hard to turn the led on, ie the mic was very not sensitive. After playing with many different values, I found that if I use 300k (10k original) for R29 and 100nf (1uf original) for C25, the sensitive increased to a point that a loud sound did flash the LED. The problem I think is that 10uf is too large for a 100nf to charge up with a short loud sound. am I correct?

Finally, I figured that if I connect collector of T10 directly to the base of T11, the sensitivity increase a lot. so what is the point of those 5 components?

[image]

Comment: Fix the schematic before asking others to look at it!  If you don't care, why should we?  Make all text horizontal and not colliding with other things.  Fix the junction dots so that they are where they need to be, but not elsewhere.  Add the values to the schematic.  It's really annoying to have to look at both schematics and the text to get values.  -1 for dumping slop on us.  There are some obvious problems, but until you stop thumbing your nose at us, you're not likely to get quality help.

Answer (score 2):

both stages of that circuit have unconstrained gain, basically gain=hfe of that transistor.

unconstrained gain is usually considered a design flaw as it leaves your design succeptable to the wide variability of transistor hfe.

all I can suggest is to replace the s8050 with something with higher gain.

Answer (score 2):

The 5 components between the two transistors are a Low pass filter, a Half Wave rectifier, and a base resistor. Your first transistor is providing gain, then the signal is low passed to only let some frequencies through. Those AC waves are then half rectified and their Voltage stored on the capacitor. That capacitor then provides the voltage needed to turn on the second transistor.

So they're there to make sure only audio frequencies get through and then to rectify the signal to use it as an input to the second transistor.

One last note: I personally think that this isn't sound to light so much as sound detection with a light indicator. Thus it likely had a certain threshold and hold time based on the electic microphone that was used.